# Remove class from my body tag. Wordpress. Genesis

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy, genesis

I have this page here: http://staging.seedcreativeacademy.co.uk/course_type/digital-marketing/ and I'm trying to use a custom taxonomy.php age for it. (taxonomy-course_type.php).

The problem being I think it's taking styles and layout from a file called page-masonry.php inside my template.

I need this functionality to display the blog, but I want to display my Custom post type differently. So I think I need to remove the class 'masonry' from th body tag.

I've tried this code to do so as the first thing in my taxonomy-course_type.php page:

```
<?php
add_filter('body_class', 'remove_body_class', 20, 2);

function remove_body_class($wp_classes)
    {
        foreach($wp_classes as $key => $value)
            {
                if ($value == 'masonry') unset($wp_classes[$key]);
            }

        return $wp_classes;
    }


genesis();
```

But it doesn't seem to do anything and my taxonomy-course_type.php doesn't seem to be being seen.

It's on the Genesis Framework, by the way, if that's any help.

Answer (score 0):

**Try Like This**

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'wpse15850_body_class', 10, 2 );

function wpse15850_body_class( $wp_classes, $extra_classes ) {

// List of the only WP generated classes allowed
$whitelist = array( 'portfolio', 'home', 'error404' );

// Filter the body classes
$wp_classes = array_intersect( $wp_classes, $whitelist );

// Add the extra classes back untouched
return array_merge( $wp_classes, (array) $extra_classes );
```

}

Comment: Thanks @Omar this doesn't seem to work though - Nothing seems to be effecting it?